# CORS error when using jsonPlaceHolder and react-admin

Tags: reactjs, cors, react-admin

I am receiving a CORS error when trying to get data from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com.

I have tested this on Google Chrome, Brave Browser, Firefox and Safari. 
I am following with the tutorial on the website. My code is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Admin, Resource, ListGuesser } from 'react-admin';
import jsonServerProvider from 'ra-data-json-server';
import './App.css';

const dataProvider = jsonServerProvider('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com');
const App = () => (
  <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}>
    <Resource name='users' list={ListGuesser} />
  </Admin>
);

export default App;
```

Error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users?_end=10&_order=ASC&_sort=id&_start=0' from origin 'http://192.168.1.175:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I have tried using:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --disable-web-security
```

to open Chrome and I still receive the error

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [custom header](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ra-data-json-server#adding-custom-headers) as the 2nd argument to `jsonServerProvider` function in order to enable cors.

**Example snippet**

```js
import { fetchUtils, Admin, Resource } from 'react-admin';
import jsonServerProvider from 'ra-data-json-server';

const httpClient = (url, options = {}) => {
    if (!options.headers) {
        options.headers = new Headers({ Accept: 'application/json' });
    }
    // add your own headers here
    options.headers.set('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'X-Total-Count'); //<----see here
    return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options);
};
const dataProvider = jsonServerProvider('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com', httpClient);

render(
    <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider} title="Example Admin">
       ...
    </Admin>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: This did not solve my problem. After adding the Access-Control-Allow-Origin as * , I still receive the error.

Comment: you need to add `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header as mentioned in the anwer(code snippet & the link)..

Comment: I have copied this exactly, and it is still not working. Also to note when I make a request to http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users?_end=10&_order=ASC&_sort=id&_start=0  on Postman or my browser I can not get a response

Comment: Actually, once I made the request using Postman, it failed but when I made it back in the browser it worked again and seems to be fine. Very weird